# How to redirect swank server output to emacs buffer? 

Tags: emacs, clojure, swank, clojurebox

I want to redirect my swank server output to an emacs buffer. I put this in ~/.swank.lisp, but this does not work-

(setf swank:*globally-redirect-io* t)

Im using Clojure box.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `clojure-jack-in`, the output of the swank server will appear in a buffer named `*swank*` (So you can see it with `C-x b *swank*`)

I you aren't using clojure-jack-in, you can still get the same effect by starting your swank server within emacs. Here's how I start mine:

```
(start-file-process "swank-process" "*swank*" "lein" "swank")
```

This starts up a swank server, and pushes all of the output into a buffer named `*swank*` (just like `clojure-jack-in` does.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [elein](https://github.com/remvee/elein)? It will allow you to start the swank server right within emacs. See the elein-swank emacs buffer to see the server output.

Comment: Or you could launch `lein swank` inside a `multi-term` buffer.